# Low stock notification email for Woocommerce using cron

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce, stock

I would like to ask if there is any way to trigger low stock threshold notification emails for all products in a Woocommerce eshop in standard intervals?

More specifically we want to run twice a script that is going to check the available quantity of stock in comparison with the low stock threshold value and if there is any shortage then the standard email of low stock threshold notification process to be triggered?

I know that my question is very general but any assistance in order to begin the implementation of the code will be appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This [part](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-dashboard.php#L244-L274) WooCommerce use to display in the dashboard widget how many products are low on stock. It may partly help you answer your question. But as you already pointed out _"I know that my question is very general"_ - so you will have to come up with something more. As your question is currently written, it is off topic on SO and it should actually be closed

Comment: Also see: [WooCommerce: Send Email to Admin Every 3 Hours (Cron Job)](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-cron-job/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to overcomplicate things. Just follow these steps:

1 - Go to WooCommerce → Settings → Products → Inventory.

2 - In the 'Notifications' section, tick 'Enable low stock notifications' and 'Enable out of stock notifications'.

3 - Enter an email address in the 'Notification recipient(s)' field.

4 - Save

Or you can use the following script:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_low_stock', 'change_stock_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // For Low stock notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_no_stock', 'change_stock_email_recipient', 10, 2 ); // For No stock notification
function change_stock_email_recipient( $recipient, $product ) {
    // HERE set your replacement email
    $recipient = 'thename@email.com';

    return $recipient;
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your instant response. We have already done the setup of email accounts. The real problem is that we want twice a day to check the whole catalog of our products in order to see the status and what products are below the low stock threshold using a cron job. I think that the specific script will be triggered every time that a product will be purchased. Thanks again!